# kubelet option to set apiserver address

Tags: api, kubernetes, nodes, kubelet

I've set up an insecure k8s master node using `hyperkube`, with an insecure API:

```sh
docker run -d --name=k8s-apiserver --net=container:etcd gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.8.5 /apiserver --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2378 --service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.1/24 --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --insecure-port=8080 --admission-control=AlwaysAdmit
```

Moving on to configuring the nodes, what option to the `docker run -d --name=kubelet gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.8.5 /kubelet` command points `kubelet` to the master `apiserver`? I can't seem to find this option using `--help`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from kubernetes version 1.8 you should use `--kubeconfig` key to specify a path to a `kubeconfig` file where is described how to connect to API server:

```
--kubeconfig string      Path to a kubeconfig file, specifying how to connect to the API server. (default "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig")
```

where `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig` something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: ~/.kube/ca.crt
    server: https://<API_IP>:<API_PORT>
  name: dev
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: dev
    user: dev
  name: dev
current-context: dev
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: dev
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate: ~/.kube/client.crt
    client-key: ~/.kube/client.key
```

So, finally you should just mount the config file inside `kubelet` docker container:

```
docker run -d -v /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig:/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig --name=kubelet gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.8.5 /kubelet
```